# Is it possible to use sudo with !requiretty for a specific command

Tags: sudo

I am trying to allow a specific command to be run under sudo without a tty. I found that I can disable requiretty for a group :

```
Defaults:%support !requiretty
```

But I dont know how to do it for a single command. Is it possible at all ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
Cmnd_Alias                NOTTYCMDS = /path/to/cmd1, /path/to/cmd2
Defaults!NOTTYCMDS        !requiretty
```

Comment: Looks promising, but this does not work for me.

Comment: This works for me running Sudo version 1.7.4p5.

Comment: I don't know why the `Defaults:USERALIAS     !requiretty` does not work for me, but this Cmnd_Alias does, and that is good enough.

Answer (score 5):

To disable sudo tty requirement for a single command use the following in the sudoers file:

```
Defaults!/path/command !requiretty
```

(This is in addition to the "Defaults requiretty" line that enables the option in general. Note about the potentially confusing syntax: the first "!" just means that what follows is a command list (compare with ":" for a user list, etc), whereas the second "!" means "not".)